# why picture doesn't show up in swing in java?

Tags: java, swing, png, image

I want to show images in a Border-layout panel in center.
I create image panel as below and then add it to the center of Border-layout.
I don't know why image doesn't show up and there is no error too.
What can be the reason and how can i fix it?

```
public class ImagePanel extends WebPanel {
private Image image;
private Image scaledImage;
private int imageWidth = 0;
private int imageHeight = 0;
//constructor
public ImagePanel() {
    super();
}
public void loadImage(String file) throws IOException {
    File filetest= new File("C:\\tmp\\axiuser\\Pictures\\CLA0014.png");
    image = ImageIO.read(filetest);//new File(file)
    imageWidth = image.getWidth(this);
    imageHeight = image.getHeight(this);
    setScaledImage();
}
//e.g., containing frame might call this from formComponentResized
public void scaleImage() {
    setScaledImage();
}
//override paintComponent
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if ( scaledImage != null ) {
        //System.out.println("ImagePanel paintComponent " + ++paintCount);
        g.drawImage(scaledImage, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
private void setScaledImage() {
    if ( image != null ) {
        //use floats so division below won't round
        float iw = imageWidth;
        float ih = imageHeight;
        float pw = this.getWidth();   //panel width
        float ph = this.getHeight();  //panel height
        if ( pw < iw || ph < ih ) {
            if ( (pw / ph) > (iw / ih) ) {
                iw = -1;
                ih = ph;
            } else {
                iw = pw;
                ih = -1;
            }
            //prevent errors if panel is 0 wide or high
            if (iw == 0) {
                iw = -1;
            }
            if (ih == 0) {
                ih = -1;
            }
            scaledImage = image.getScaledInstance(
                        new Float(iw).intValue(), new Float(ih).intValue(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
        } else {
            scaledImage = image;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: See my answer below, try it with a JPEG file and see if it works.

Comment: WHat's the size of your ImagePanel? If you are using a layout manager, you should also set the preferredSize of the ImagePanel to the size of your scaledImage, otherwise, the ImagePanel size will be 0x0 and you will never see your image.

Answer (score 1):

Just override `getPreferredSize()` of your `JPanel`, as you are doing with `paintComponent(...)` method. Let it return some `Dimension` object, something like :

```
public Dimension getPreferredSize()
{
    return (new Dimension(300, 300));
}
```

That will allow you to see your images.

Answer (score 1):

You never call your method

```
public void loadImage (String file)
```

SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
    private Image image;
    private Image scaledImage;

    public void loadImage (String filename) throws IOException {
        image = ImageIO.read (new File (filename)); 
        setScaledImage ();
    }

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent (g);
        if ( scaledImage != null) {
            // System.out.println ("ImagePanel paintComponent ");
            g.drawImage (scaledImage, 0, 0, this);
        }
    } 

    private void setScaledImage () {
        if (image != null) {
            //use floats so division below won't round
            int imageWidth = image.getWidth (this);
            int imageHeight = image.getHeight (this);
            float iw = imageWidth;
            float ih = imageHeight;
            float pw = this.getWidth ();   //panel width
            float ph = this.getHeight ();  //panel height
            if ( pw < iw || ph < ih) {
                if ( (pw / ph) > (iw / ih)) {
                    iw = -1;
                    ih = ph;
                } else {
                    iw = pw;
                    ih = -1;
                }
                //prevent errors if panel is 0 wide or high
                if (iw == 0) {
                    iw = -1;
                }
                if (ih == 0) {
                    ih = -1;
                }
                scaledImage = image.getScaledInstance (
                new Float (iw).intValue (), new Float (ih).intValue (), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
            } else {
                scaledImage = image;
            }
        }
    }   

    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {
        ImagePanel ip = new ImagePanel ();
        ip.loadImage ("./sample.png");
        JFrame jf = new JFrame ();
        jf.setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
        jf.add (ip, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jf.setSize (400, 400); 
        jf.setLocation (150, 150);
        jf.setVisible (true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Scaling doesn't work yet, but here you have something to start. (Note that I renamed the image).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is no Reader defined for `*.png`.You can check the list of available image readers using `ImageIO.getReaderFormatNames()`

Comment: There should be: GIF, JPEG, PNG are covered as part of the javax.imageio RI.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set the panel as not opaque:

```
setOpaque(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing when your program will actually invoke `paintComponent()` it's impossible to tell. But if you call your `loadImage` method *after* you have already shown the GUI (`setVisible`) you would need to invoke `repaint()` or `invalidate()` on the panel in order to trigger a repaint of the component (and update the GUI that way).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `JLabel` for displaying images.

```
JLabel myLabel=new JLabel();
myLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\tmp\\axiuser\\Pictures\\CLA0014.png"));
```